How to load offline maps on OSM android
I have had a problem for a few days and it is that I am not able to read and paint the tiles on the offline map... The code where I tell you how to read the map is this:
osmMapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
File osmdroidBasePath = new File(requireActivity().getFilesDir(), "osmdroid");
File osmdroidTileCache = new File(osmdroidBasePath, "tiles");
Configuration.getInstance().setOsmdroidBasePath(osmdroidBasePath);
Configuration.getInstance().setOsmdroidTileCache(osmdroidTileCache);

File sqliteFile = new File(osmdroidBasePath, "burgos.sqlite");

if (sqliteFile.exists()) {
    configureOSMDroid(sqliteFile);
} else {
    Log.e("osmdroid", "El archivo SQLite no existe en la ruta especificada.");
    // Abre el selector de archivos para permitir al usuario seleccionar el archivo
    openFilePicker();
}



private void openFilePicker() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*"); // Permite seleccionar cualquier tipo de archivo
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            if (uri != null) {
                new Thread(() -> {
                    copyFileToInternalStorage(uri);
                    requireActivity().runOnUiThread(this::checkAndConfigureOSMDroid);
                }).start();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void checkAndConfigureOSMDroid() {
    File osmdroidBasePath = new File(requireContext().getFilesDir(), "osmdroid");
    File sqliteFile = new File(osmdroidBasePath, "burgos.sqlite");

    if (sqliteFile.exists()) {
        Log.d("osmdroid", "YA EXISTE: " + sqliteFile.getAbsolutePath());
        configureOSMDroid(sqliteFile);
    } else {
        Log.d("osmdroid", "NO EXISTE");
        Log.e("osmdroid", "El archivo SQLite no existe en la ruta especificada.");
    }
}

private void copyFileToInternalStorage(Uri uri) {
    if (uri == null) {
        Log.e("osmdroid", "La URI proporcionada es nula.");
        return;
    }

    File osmdroidBasePath = new File(requireContext().getFilesDir(), "osmdroid");
    if (!osmdroidBasePath.exists()) {
        osmdroidBasePath.mkdirs();
    }

    File destFile = new File(osmdroidBasePath, "burgos.sqlite");

    try (InputStream in = requireContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
         OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFile)) {

        if (in == null) {
            Log.e("osmdroid", "No se pudo abrir el InputStream para la URI proporcionada.");
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        Log.i("osmdroid", "Archivo copiado exitosamente al almacenamiento interno.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("osmdroid", "Error al copiar el archivo: ", e);
    }
}

private void configureOSMDroid(File sqliteFile) {
    try {
        OfflineTileProvider tileProvider = new OfflineTileProvider(new SimpleRegisterReceiver(requireContext()), new File[]{sqliteFile});
        ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource("burgos", 0, 18, 256, ".png", new String[]{"http://localhost"});
        tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);

        osmMapView.setTileProvider(tileProvider);
        osmMapView.setTileSource(tileSource);
        osmMapView.getOverlayManager().clear();
        TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(tileProvider, requireContext());
        osmMapView.getOverlayManager().add(tilesOverlay);
        osmMapView.setUseDataConnection(false); // Modo offline

        Log.d("osmdroid", "Tiles offline configurados correctamente.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("osmdroid", "Error loading offline tiles", e);
    }
}

And the log:
2024-07-29 14:00:39.007  7705-7705  StorageUtils            com.itcl.centinela                   I  /data/user/0/com.itcl.centinela/files/osmdroid is writable
2024-07-29 14:00:39.020  7705-7705  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   I  Using tile source: Mapnik
2024-07-29 14:00:39.022  7705-7705  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   I  Tile cache increased from 0 to 9
2024-07-29 14:00:39.048  7705-7705  osmdroid                com.itcl.centinela                   E  El archivo SQLite no existe en la ruta especificada.
2024-07-29 14:00:39.160  7705-7705  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   I  Tile cache increased from 9 to 45
2024-07-29 14:00:43.668  7705-7948  osmdroid                com.itcl.centinela                   I  Archivo copiado exitosamente al almacenamiento interno.
2024-07-29 14:00:43.738  7705-7705  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   I  Tile cache increased from 45 to 54
2024-07-29 14:00:43.794  7705-7705  osmdroid                com.itcl.centinela                   D  YA EXISTE: /data/user/0/com.itcl.centinela/files/osmdroid/burgos.sqlite
2024-07-29 14:00:43.794  7705-7705  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   I  Tile cache increased from 0 to 9
2024-07-29 14:00:43.798  7705-7912  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   D  TileLoader failed to load tile due to mWriter being null (map shutdown?)
2024-07-29 14:00:43.798  7705-7912  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   D  TileLoader failed to load tile due to mWriter being null (map shutdown?)
2024-07-29 14:00:43.798  7705-7912  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   D  TileLoader failed to load tile due to mWriter being null (map shutdown?)
2024-07-29 14:00:43.798  7705-7912  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   D  TileLoader failed to load tile due to mWriter being null (map shutdown?)
2024-07-29 14:00:43.798  7705-7912  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   D  TileLoader failed to load tile due to mWriter being null (map shutdown?)
2024-07-29 14:00:43.798  7705-7912  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   D  TileLoader failed to load tile due to mWriter being null (map shutdown?)
2024-07-29 14:00:43.798  7705-7912  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   D  TileLoader failed to load tile due to mWriter being null (map shutdown?)
2024-07-29 14:00:43.798  7705-7912  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   D  TileLoader failed to load tile due to mWriter being null (map shutdown?)
2024-07-29 14:00:43.799  7705-7912  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   D  TileLoader failed to load tile due to mWriter being null (map shutdown?)
2024-07-29 14:00:43.799  7705-7912  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   D  TileLoader failed to load tile due to mWriter being null (map shutdown?)
2024-07-29 14:00:43.799  7705-7912  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   D  TileLoader failed to load tile due to mWriter being null (map shutdown?)
2024-07-29 14:00:43.801  7705-7705  osmdroid                com.itcl.centinela                   D  Tiles offline configurados correctamente.
2024-07-29 14:00:43.806  7705-7705  OsmDroid                com.itcl.centinela                   I  Tile cache increased from 9 to 54
2024-07-29 14:00:50.647  7705-7971  .itcl.centinela         com.itcl.centinela                   W  Long monitor contention with owner approximater (7973) at java.io.InputStream org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileArchiveProvider.getInputStream(long, org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.ITileSource)(MapTileFileArchiveProvider.java:207) waiters=6 in java.io.InputStream org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileArchiveProvider.getInputStream(long, org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.ITileSource) for 143ms
The map is blank, could you help me?
Thanks in advance
